# Does deliberately knocking the king over end the game?

Tags: etiquette, otb-chess

When I play with my friend, he will often knock his own king over when he is going to lose.

He ends the game and says, "I lose".

Is this permissible?

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with it, I have seen many players resign this way.

Comment: It's very typical and acceptable.  He is admitting defeat.

Comment: it seem generally to happened without some legal rules to define it. thanks.

Comment: You can actually get shot for this in the hood, disqualified in tournament matches. etc. No, but seriously...what are you expecting a resignation to look like? Do you want him to bow down to your feet?

Comment: There are three different questions here: (1) Is deliberately knocking over the king *forbidden*? (2) Is deliberately knocking over the king *bad etiquette*? (3) Does deliberately knocking over the king *end the game*? Note that some forbidden conduct causes the game to end immediately with a result other than resignation (eg using an electronic device, at least under FIDE rules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a [link](http://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/knocking-your-king-down-when-resigning) addressing this question exactly i quote:

> It depends on the way you do it, generally it's not rude, though.
>
> Once I was playing a tough game against the late GM Wojo, and got a
>   balanced and complicated position, but also considerable time
>   pressure. After the time pressure was over I realized that I have
>   totally blown up my position, played 41.Kg1-g0 and pressed the clock.
>   Wojo was surprised at first, but later he had a good laugh.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, players often tip their king over to indicate that they are resigning.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this permissible?

This mostly depends on the chess customs in your country. Personally, I have never ever seen somebody in past 13 years who did this in official tournament. But in unofficial games with friends this is totally acceptable.

Comment: From my experiences, most games end with resignation, not checkmate.  Usually the losing player stops the clock and doesn't actually tip his King.  But I have seen it during tournament play.

Comment: I frequently see this in official tournaments.